# C++ templates: Select different type based on value of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

How do I accomplish the following in C++, and what is doing such things called?

```
template <bool S>
class NuclearPowerplantControllerFactoryProviderFactory {
  // if S == true
  typedef int data_t;
  // if S == false
  typedef unsigned int data_t;
};
```

Comment: There are two many `Factory` words in this class name, I think you're thinking in Java.

Comment: No, you need your controller making factory provider factories in all languages.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By **specialization**:

```
template <bool> class Foo;

template <> class Foo<true>
{
  typedef int data_t;
};

template <> class Foo<false>
{
  typedef unsigned int data_t;
};
```

You can choose to make one of the two cases the primary template and the other one the specialization, but I prefer this more symmetric version, given that `bool` can only have two values.

---

<sub>If this is the first time you see this, you might also like to think about *partial* specialization:</sub>

```
template <typename T> struct remove_pointer     { typedef T type; };
template <typename U> struct remove_pointer<U*> { typedef U type; };
```

---

As @Nawaz says, the easiest way is probably to `#include <type_traits>` and say:

```
typedef typename std::conditional<S, int, unsigned int>::type data_t;
```

Comment: `template <typename U> struct remove_pointer<T*> { typedef U type; };` ?

Comment: Every time I learn new C++ syntax, the readability of all future code I write suffer...

Comment: @porgarmingduod: On the contrary! Look at my last line in the updated post: One line, and it's totally self-descriptive. If you use the right tools and building blocks, your code will actually become *more* readable and less verbose. You replace opaque syntax nonsense with self-descriptive one-liners.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are right, I was joking. I'm already using std::conditional to greatly simplify a hairy class; making it more generic and useful with less code.

Answer (score 10):

@Kerrek has answered the question sufficiently, but that can be more generic as follows:

```
template<bool b, typename T, typename U>
struct select
{
    typedef T type;
};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct select<false, T, U>
{
    typedef U type;
};
```

And use as:

```
template <bool S>
class NuclearPowerplantControllerFactoryProviderFactory 
{
  typedef typename select<S, int, unsigned int>::type data_t;
  //use data_t as data type
};
```

If `S` is true, the first type argument in `select` will be selected, or else second type argument will be selected. It is generic because you specify both types in `select<>`, and based on the value of the boolean, `select<b,T,U>::type` returns either first type, or second type.

Comment: This is also known as `std::conditional` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: std::conditional was exactly what I needed. Though your answer is more general so I'll pick that for posterity.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: The golden rule is that you should be *aware* of how to use template specialization to make compile-time decisions, and *then* you look at the `<type_trait>` library and see all the wonderful tools that are already made for you to use :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since C++14, it can and should be done using std::conditional<> , see
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

[under the hood, it is the same as solution suggested by @Nawaz but standard solutions are always preferable whenever available]