# C++ Getting objects with IDs at runtime

Tags: c++, templates, runtime

Let's suppose we have the following objects:

```
struct A{
    static const int ID = 1;
};

struct B{
    static const int ID = 2;
};

struct C{
    static const int ID = 3;
};

struct D{
    static const int ID = 4;
};

struct Collection{
    std::vector<A> o1;
    std::vector<B> o2;
    std::vector<C> o3;
    std::vector<D> o4;
};

Collection collection;
```

What I want to do is getting references to some of the `vector`s of the `Collection`. There should be three different ways to retrieve these:

1. By type of `vector`, e.g. `collection.get<A>();`
2. By ID on compile time which is defined by every object that is held by a `vector`, e.g. `collection.get<4>();`
3. By ID on runtime, e.g. `collection.get(id);`

Case 1 is easy as it can be transformed into case 2 with `T::ID`. Case 2 can be implemented with template specialization (although it looks ugly if I'd have lots of objects).
Case 3 is making a lot of trouble. Without some giant `if` or `switch` statements it seams to be nearly impossible, let alone deducing the return type.

**My questions are:**

- **Is there a way to make case 2 more elegant?**
- **How should I implement case 3?**

Comment: Will there always only be `A, B, C, D`?

Comment: Probably no, there will be at least 30.

Comment: You have a runtime value. You don't know what it is. You need to operate on a different type depending on that value, meaning a completely different code path (even if it's a different instantiation of the same function template). That means a run-time branch. So, you either have a `switch` or a `map<int,function>` - those are pretty much your choices.

Comment: But how would I return the `vector` from a `switch` statement? The compiler moans that the return type can't be deduced.

Comment: You can't - the switch needs to dispatch into a type-specific codepath. Think of it like a Visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things you can do, and things you can never do. What you're asking for is not that simple, and needs hard work.

1 and 2 are difficult, but achievable. First, [create a static map of all type-IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490835/how-to-build-a-compile-time-key-value-store), then [use the static result to choose the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243134/c-templates-select-different-type-based-on-value-of-template-parameter).

Now 3... well... sorry to tell you it's impossible! To provide a counter-example that proves what I'm saying: You can never create a function that chooses the return type at runtime. But...

There's something you can do, which is basically what the LLVM people did to get rid of `dynamic_cast`, but it's too much code.

First, case a base abstract class, and make all these classes derive from it, and make it contain the ID:

```
struct Base{
    virtual int getClassID() = 0;
    static Base* CreateObject(int ID) //consider using shared_ptr here
        {
        switch(ID) {
        case A::ID:
            return new A;
        }            
        case B::ID:
            return new B;
        default:
            return nullptr;
        }
        //...
    }
}

struct A : public Base {
    static const int ID = 1;
    int getClassID() override {
        return ID;
    }
};

struct B : public Base {
    static const int ID = 2;
    int getClassID() override {
        return ID;
    }
};

struct C : public Base {
    static const int ID = 3;
    int getClassID() override {
        return ID;
    }
};

struct D : public Base {
    static const int ID = 4;
    int getClassID() override {
        return ID;
    }
};
```

Now, to instantiate a new class, you use you Base class.

```
Base* c = Base::CreateObject(3); //object of C
```

Now, finally, you create your magic cast operator:

```
template <typename T>
T* MyMagicCast(Base* obj)
{
    if(obj->getClassID() ISVALID) //Then use the ID to make sure that T matches the ID
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(obj);
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

And this will do the runtime stuff for you. With this method, you have the advantage that all types operation can be done by calling the base + you're not using any RTTI. Now ONLY if you need something specific to one of the types you have (A,B,C,D), you use `MyMagicCast()` to cast to their type.

PS: The code is off the top of my head, so there might be slight typos/errors.

Comment: Thanks for your example, I'll take a look at it.